# ASP.NET MVC3 ValueProvider drops string input to a double property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, value-provider

I'm attempting to validate the input of a text box which corresponds to a property of type `double` in my model. If the user inputs `"foo"` I want to know about it so I can display an error. However, the `ValueProvider` is dropping the value silently (no errors are added to the `ModelState`).

In a normal submission, I fill in `"2"` for the text box corresponding to `myDouble` and submit the form. 
Inspecting `controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form` shows that `myDouble=2`, among other correct inputs. `bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("myDouble") == 2`, as expected. The `bindingContext.ModelState.Count == 6` and `bindingContext.ModelState["myDouble"].Errors.Count == 0`. Everything is good and the model binds as expected.

Then I fill in "foo" for the text box corresponding to `myDouble` and submitted the form.
Inspecting `controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form` shows that `myDouble=foo`, which is what I expected. However, `bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("myDouble") == null` and `bindingContext.ModelState.Count == 5` (The exact number isn't important, but it's one less than before). Looking at the `ValueProvider`, is as if `myDouble` was never submitted and the model binding occurs as if it wasn't. This makes it difficult to differentiate between a bad input and no input.

Is this the expected behavior of `ValueProvider`? Is there a way to get `ValueProvider` to report when conversion fails without implementing a custom `ValueProvider`? Thanks!

Comment: Decorate the field with RequiredAttribute.

Comment: Can you show a little bit of code for the model and that tiny bit needed of the view, because i've tested it and `ModelState.IsValid` is `false` for a `double` receiving text.

Comment: @Silvermind - Are you certain you don't mean `double?`

Comment: @MystereMan I'm sorry, my bad. I did mean text to double submittance but I tested it on ASP.NET MVC4 ;)

Comment: @Silvermind - I guess that wasn't clear.  The ? was inside the code bracket indicating a nullable double.  Are you sure you didn't mean a nullable `double?` rather `double`?

Comment: @MystereMan Could be true, because I wanted to test both and probably forgot the non nullable. I will test it again later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem here is that your model has a type of `double`.

The problem is that `double` cannot be null, and as such will default to a value of 0, thus on submit.. if the `ValueProvider` returns null, the value of the field will still be 0 and validation will pass.

You should make the `double` nullable, by using `double?` and then add a Required attribute to the property.  If the type is not required, then you can add a regular expression validator.

Comment: Nice solution. Odd behavior tough for the Validator. I 'm still gonna check in MVC4, cause I'm curious if it happens there too.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC4 Will handle it correctly, so submitting text to a non-attributed and non-nullable `double` property will set `ModelState.IsValid = false` with the message: `The value 'foo' is not valid for MyDouble.`

Comment: @Silvermind - thanks for chasing that down.  I wonder if this was an improvement in MVC4

Comment: @MystereMan Thanks, changing `MyDouble` to type `double?` and decorating it with `[Required]` did it. The `ModelState` is coming back invalid with the error `"MyDouble is required"`. Not the most accurate description of what's actually happening but good enough in my case to determine that a bad input was submitted.

Comment: @Silvermind That's good news. I'll be happy to clean up this fix once we upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom model binding logic using by implementing IModelBinder.  This will put the data validation logic at the model binding level - thus being usable for any type of ValueProvider.  In your situation, the model binder would determine that when myDouble = "foo" is not a double and add an exception to the ModelState errors showing the invalid value.

```
public class CustomDoubleBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        }
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");
        }
        decimal tempDouble = 0m;
        if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName) != null)
        {
            if (double.TryParse(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).AttemptedValue, out tempDecimal))
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState[bindingContext.ModelName].Errors.Add("Error parsing double value: " + bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).AttemptedValue);
            }
        }

        return tempDouble;
    }
}
```

Having created this custom model binder, you will then need to register it in the Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(double)] = new CustomDoubleBinder();
}
```